# Using Python Imaging Library (PIL) in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, pydev

I am attempting to use PIL in Eclipse. I have managed to install the following packages so that this code runs without error:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
from pylab import *
from scipy.misc import *

im = array(Image.open('empire.jpg').convert('L'))
```

However, the following:

```
imshow(im)
```

Produces the error:

```
    raise RuntimeError('Could not execute image viewer.')
    RuntimeError: Could not execute image viewer.
```

I tried to install the basic Image Viewer from the Eclipse Marketplace. It doesn't solve the problem.

Does anybody know how to get Eclipse display the image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ran OK for me (Windows, Python2.6). I commented out the unused scipy import, and added `show()` at the end

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me too. Just removing the unused scipy.misc import removed the problem. Perhaps there was a conflict somewhere with the image viewer...

Comment: I added a reply with the same info. Since this helped, perhaps you could mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ran OK for me (Windows, Python2.6), with the following two changes:

1. commented out the unused scipy import
2. added show() at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
pl.show()
```

works.

If your import like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
```